# Why does memset not fill a 2D integer array properly?

Tags: c, arrays

I used `memset()` to fill a 2D integer array as below.

```
int main(){
    int** a = calloc( 2, sizeof(int*) );
    int i = 0;
    for( ; i<2; i++ ){
        a[ i ] = calloc( 2, sizeof( int ) );
    }

    memset( a, 0, 4 * sizeof( int ) ) ;

    for( i = 0; i < 2; i++ ){
        int j = 0;
        for( ; j < 2; j++ ){
            printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

> Segmentation fault

But if I replace `memset( a, 0, 4 * sizeof( int ) )` with:

```
for( i = 0; i < 2; i++ ){
        int j = 0;
        for( ; j < 2; j++ ){
            a[ i ][ j ] = 0;
        }
    }
```

The output is correct:

```
0 0 
0 0
```

Can anybody tell me why the `memset()` did not work there?

Comment: You don't have a 2D array. You have an array of pointers to other arrays.

Comment: try `int (*a)[2] = calloc( 2, sizeof(*a));  /*memset( a, 0, 4 * sizeof( int) );*/`
`

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use a debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: that's an array of pointers to another array, not 2D array

Comment: if some answer helps you, [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it by clicking the green check

Answer (score 4):

While allocating memory, you have allocated `2, sizeof(int*)` amount to `a`, and while doing `memset()`, you use `4 * sizeof(int)`. They necessarily do not represent same amount of memory (more importantly, that's even not what you wanted) hence there's a over-run of allocated memory. This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which causes the segmentation fault.

Having said that, you don't need to `memset()` a `calloc()`ed memory to 0. It already is.

Answer (score 4):

When you write like this

```
int** a = calloc( 2, sizeof(int*) );
int i = 0;
for( ; i<2; i++ ){
    a[ i ] = calloc( 2, sizeof( int ) );
}
```

You get in the memory something like this

```
        +--+       +--+--+
a[0]    |  |-----> |  |  |
        +--+       +--+--+ 
a[1]    |  |   
        +--+  
            \      +--+--+
             +---> |  |  |
                   +--+--+
```

memset expects memory to be as a continuous memory block, but that is not what
you are giving it, so with `memset(a,0,4*sizeof(int))` you are writing beyond 
a[1] out in the blue.

With a[0][1] you are doing two deferences, one for the first vector a[0]..a[1]
and one for the second vector that is why it works in your for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee that all your different allocations are contiguous to each other. The only way to initialize correctly your memory is to initialize each part that was allocated. You can use `memset` but this way:

```
    int** a = calloc( 2, sizeof(int*) );
    memset( a, 0, 2 * sizeof( int* ) ) ;     // initialize the two pointers
    int i = 0;
    for( ; i<2; i++ ){
        a[ i ] = calloc( 2, sizeof( int ) );
        memset( a[i], 0, 2 * sizeof( int ) ) ;  // initializes the two ints
    }
```

Note that initializing to zero is not necessary since you used `calloc`.

Comment: 1) Certainly the 2nd `memset( a, 0, 2 * sizeof( int ) ) ;  // initializes the two ints` --> `memset( a[i], 0, 2 * sizeof( int ) ) ;`  2) Why `memset()` the arrays at all with 0 as `calloc()` zeros the allocated memory.